# I have a few questions about Whonix/Tor

Tags: whonix

I'm a new user to Tor/Whonix

I have a question about it and I hope you can help. Or, if there is documentation that answers each question I have, feel free to post it and I am sorry for wasting your time.

I really don't want to run an **exit node** I hear people have contact from their ISP/Police etc when operating an exit relay. Does Whonix ever operate as an exit node? From what I understand, the exit node is the only unencrypted part of the chain and therefore anyone can see what people have been searching.

I have absolutely no intention of doing anything illegal on it, I'm just worried about being held responsible for someone else's behavior. We were speaking about it in a lecture today but they would not show us the "dark web" so I want to see what it's like.

Cheers for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-issue.

Whonix by default is using the Tor network as a client only. (Changing this is even difficult.)

You won't be running any kind of relay by using Whonix.

The same goes for the Tor Browser Bundle (TBB) and Tails.